# What does this language?

Tags: grammar

I'm a beginner and I'm doing some exercises on grammars. 
for example:

`L (0 ^ n 1 ^ m 2 ^ k such that n = m and m = k)`

I do not understand, if n = 1 means that m = 1, then k = 1?

**I found two possible grammars:**

TYPE 0 (Turing Machine)

```
S => e | ABC | SABC
A => 0
B => 1
C => 2
20 => 02
10 => 01
21 => 12
```

or

```
S => e | 0SBC | 0BC
0B => 01
1B => 11
1C => 12
2C => 22
CB => BC
```

Comment: Of no particular value: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=L+%280+%5E+n+1+%5E+m+2+%5E+k%29+such+that+n+%3D+m+and+m+%3D+k

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in `n = m and m = k` if `n = 1` then `m = 1` and thus `k = 1`.

Note that `n = m and m = k` is also written `n = m = k` both mean that all three variables `n` `m` and `k` have the same value and are equal to each other, due to the transitivity of equality.

Comment: thank you, then the string that generates this language is: null, 012, 001122, 000111222 etc.

Comment: I tried to do the grammar: S => e | SABC - A => 0 - B => 1 - C => 2  - 20 => 02 - 10 => 01 - 21 => 12   I think it works